# Should i implement JMS server and client in one or two projects?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms

I have a test assignment where i need to implement communication between web client and server. WebClient is a simple web application that receives user's requests and then pushes them to ActiveMQ, so Server can handle those requests and push response back to ActiveMQ.

As i am new to JMS, my question is: should i implement client and server in one project, or decouple them?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's up to you but in real world it would be even two different teams who create server and client.

Answer (score 1):

If you imagine a scenario where you have 2 different components interacting, I would implement client and server in two different projects deployed inside 2 different EAR projects.

However in Java Enterprise applications you can use JMS to implement parallelism: you can deploy many consumers and consume concurrently the message produced by the client, achieving parallelism. In this case I think a single project for both client and server it's suitable even in real world applications.